# Perform a not true checked binding on knockout js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, checked

i have an input type checkbox in knockout js and i whant to perform the "not true" action when this checkbox is checked. Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: !IsVisible"/>
```

But this is not working.
I know that i can call IsHidden and set the common checked binding, but i have a special situation in witch i need this behavior.

Comment: For an interesting exercise, I posted a Q&A question that demonstrates a generic "not" binding, which allows you to write the html like this: `<input type="checkbox" data-bind="not: {checked: isVisible}" />`  (http://stackoverflow.com/q/16368784/91189)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can evaluate the observable directly in the binding, and your idea should work.

like this:  `<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: !IsVisible()"/>`

Note, however, this loses the "observability", which is probably not what you want.

An alternative is to create an `IsHidden` property that is computed off of IsVisible.

```
var ViewModel = function (model) {
    var self = this;
    self.IsVisible = ko.observable(model.IsVisible);
    self.IsHidden = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return !self.IsVisible();
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            self.IsVisible(!newValue);
        }
    });
}
```

[**See the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/MPAS4/1/)

Comment: Exactly, i don't want to loos that observability

Answer (score 5):

Define a custom binding.  See "[Simplifying and cleaning up views in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html)" which has a section very, very similar to what you're asking for.  Basically, something like this should work (NOTE: not tested):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.notChecked = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update(element, function() { return!value; });
  }
};
```

Then you could do:

```
data-bind="notChecked: IsVisible"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because with ! you're performing a function on the observable. Use this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: !IsVisible()"/>
```

Comment: Ahh, just read the previous answer which states exactly this.