# How to negate the isVisible binding in Knockout using a generic "not" binding?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is is possible to implement a "not" binding using Knockout?  Basically, I want to negate the binding value, but retain the two-way binding/observability.

In my view model, I have a property, `isVisible`, but my UI requirements dictate that I provide a checkbox to represent the hidden, or "not visible" state.  I would prefer not to create a duplicate or second property to track the negated state.

Code such as this does not work fully because it does not pass the observable to the binding:

```
<label>Is Hidden?<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: !isVisible()" /></label>
```

*Note: This is a Q&A style question - Although I'm posting an answer, I'm also very interested in any different or improved answers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a "not" binding that can be used for any single-parameter "bool" type of binding, such as `checked`, `visible`, `enable`, etc.

Use the binding like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="not: {checked: isVisible}" />
```

The `not` binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.not = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        //expects a single, truthy/falsy binding, 
        //    such as checked, visible, enable, etc.
        var binding = valueAccessor();
        var observable = binding[Object.keys(binding)[0]];
        var notComputed = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return !observable();
            },
            write: function (newValue) {
                observable(!newValue);
            }
        });
        var newBinding = {};
        newBinding[Object.keys(binding)[0]] = notComputed;
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, newBinding, viewModel);
    }
};
```

I haven't really tried to polish the binding, but it seems to be fully functional.

[**See the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/MPAS4/2/)